# How to run a python script on Google Cloud Platform VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a python script that works well locally on my computer, that I have also stored a copy of in a data bucket on Google Cloud Platform.

I have also set up a VM with Debian Stretch.

The python program uses several libraries if that matters.

How do I go from here to running the script on the VM?

Before trying the VM-way, I tried running the script, a requirement.txt, and an app.yaml file using the App Engine, which seemed to work but the process times out in the cloud shell without any output/result.

I've tried to read the Google Cloud Platform documentation, Googling, looking for videos on youtube etc, but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: did you try the "hello world" app, to check if all your pieces are in the same places? (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

Compute Engine instances include recent versions of Python, however it does not include pip. Currently the documentation indicates you need to install it:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Once done and if you still have issues, take a look to this thread:

[Run python script on Google Cloud Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541472/run-python-script-on-google-cloud-compute-engine)

It may help you to find and fix errors when running the script.