# How can I run a python script from PyCharm on GCP Compute Engine?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to run some machine learning algorithms such as PCA and KNN with a relatively large dataset of images (>2000 rgb images) in order to classify these images.

My source code is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from glob import glob
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn import preprocessing


data = []

# Read images from file
for filename in glob('Images/*.jpg'):

    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    img = np.array(img)

    # Check that all my images are of the same resolution
    if height == 529 and width == 940:

        # Reshape each image so that it is stored in one line
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        data.append(img)

# Normalise data
data = np.array(data)
Norm = preprocessing.Normalizer()
Norm.fit(data)
data = Norm.transform(data)

# PCA model
pca = PCA(0.95)
pca.fit(data)
data = pca.transform(data)

# K-Nearest neighbours
knn = neighbors.NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='minkowski').fit(data)
distances, indices = knn.kneighbors(data)

print(indices)
```

However, my laptop is not sufficient for this task as it needs many hours in order to process more than 700 rgb images. So I need to use the computational resources of an online platform (e.g. like the ones provided by GCP). How can I simply use some of the resources of GCP (faster CPUs, GPU etc) to run my source code above?

Can I simply make a call from Pycharm to Compute Engine API (after a I have created a virtual machine in it) to run my python script?

Or the only possible solution is either to install PyCharm in the virtual machine and run the python script in it or do what these answers suggest in the virtual machine ([Running a python script on Google Cloud Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455680/running-a-python-script-on-google-cloud-compute-engine), [Run python script on Google Cloud Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541472/run-python-script-on-google-cloud-compute-engine?noredirect=1&lq=1))?

Answer (score 1):

First it sounds like you'll need to move your images into somewhere GCP will be able to access them, like Google Cloud Storage (GCS). You can't run your code on GCP without having the images there as well. You can then use Compute Engine to run your python code, maybe in a docker container. You'll have to expand out your code so that you can kick off the process, access GCS to get the images and store the result somewhere.

I would look into using [Google Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/), if you're serious about about using the cloud to process a lot of information then Dataproc is managed service for doing a lot of work in a scaled way. It can pull information from GCS, run your code, spread the load across a cluster of machines and store the results in a database like BigQuery or Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hmm, ok I got it. However, I have at least one question: how will I use/import python libraries like numpy, scikit etc in the docker container?

Comment: Also, the answer you are giving suggests that I cannot really use GCP Compute Engine directly from PyCharm as I am doing with, for example, Cloud Vision API for Optical Character Recognition. Am I right? (I had the impression that running a python script (from PyCharm) on GCP Compute Engine would be equally simple as calling directly a GCP API by simply adding some lines of codes in the same python script in PyCharm).

Comment: @Universalis So Compute engine and Cloud Vision are 2 different concepts. Compute Engine is a managed service around virtual machines, so the api for compute engine is all about managing those vm instances, adding/removing. This allows you to automate the process of setuping vm's.  Cloud Vision Api is a service that has a very specific purpose of reading images and responding with information about the contents of image. Running code is a whole different beast, all the cloud providers offer services for PaaS. Closet thing to what your looking. This is running code in the cloud without

Comment: worrying about the platform infrastructure e.g. setuping up a VM. Have a look at tutorials around python in docker, theres loads and they show you how to include your dependencies. Also checkout AppEngine its another service you might find useful. Good luck and have fun! :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your thorough comment. However, keep in mind that I did not really say that I want only add few lines of source code in my python script in PyCharm and then be able to run it in a vm in GCP Compute Engine. I said specifically that I want simply to add few lines of source code in my python script in PyCharm AFTER I have set up a vm in in GCP Compute Engine.

Comment: Do you find it a good idea to set up a windows virtual machine on GCP Compute Engine and install PyCharm in it to run my python scripts or this is impossible in GCP?

Comment: Ok so I get what your saying. You essentially want to throw grunt at the problem. Yes you can setup a windows vm in GCP but you'll have to install and setup all the software you need. You'll also need the images publicly accessible or uploaded to the VM. Is this a one off operation you want to perform or something you'll repeat? Using this method is a very inefficient way of running your code. Just running  PyCharm will use up large chunks of memory. This will translate into costing you more as you'll need a more powerful vm