# Python scripts running on remote/virtual machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtual-machine, remote-access

Some tasks I need to execute with Python scripts. It takes long so I am looking for alternatives rather than keep my computer on and running for days.

(Windows, Python 2.7)

1. Download thousands of audio files from a paid API (it takes days due to speed limit. Each file size is small, but total number of files is large.)
2. Split these downloaded files
   Upload another batch of similar files to the downloaded location (total file size will be around two gigabytes only)
3. Process above files (select and remix)
4. Print out a simple line when 1 file is processed

The Python scripts are not very complicated, but required relevant packages.

For it's time consuming, rather than keeping a computer on and running for days, what are the options that, I can set up and start the task somewhere, just come back in days for the results and output?

It looks like the other [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455680/running-a-python-script-on-google-cloud-compute-engine), but I'm not sure if it supports file storage and export of result part etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service such as [AWS Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), you will have a monster to run your codes, but there is a fee attached to it.